# How to use the QEMU that I compiled with my libvirt? qxl error

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, libvirt

I've been trying to run a QEMU that I compiled by myself. I could run it if I use plain qemu commands, but it gets wrong when I substitute the system QEMU with the one I compiled.

If you use the `virus edit VM_name`, you could edit the configuration. I changed

```
<emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
```

into

```
<emulator>/home/user/Documents/qemu/build/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
```

You may get something like below

```
 <devices>
    <emulator>/home/user/Documents/qemu/build/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2' discard='unmap'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/ubuntu20.04.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
```

I got the permission denied issue at first, and I referenced this question below.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471345/changing-libvirt-emulator-permission-denied

After I changed AppArmor configuration (Add "/home/user/Documents/qemu/build/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 PUx,"), I get this:

"error: unsupported configuration: domain configuration does not support video model 'qxl'
Failed. Try again? [y,n,i,f,?]:"

My system is ubuntu-22.04LTS, Libvirt version is 8.0.0(installed via apt-get), the QEMU in the system is 6.2.0 (installed via apt-get). The QEMU I compiled is from https://gitlab.com/virtio-fs/qemu.git, and the branch is virtio-fs-dev (version is QEMU 7.0.0).

Are there any features that I forgot to enable when compiling QEMU? Or are there any tutorials to use the QEMU I compiled? Thank you!

---

### Update

I find the qxl problem above is solved if I changed to an older model. But I still got the permission denied problem.

This is what I get from "dmesg":

```
[12227.019203] virbr0: port 2(vnet5) entered blocking state
[12227.019211] virbr0: port 2(vnet5) entered disabled state
[12227.019390] device vnet5 entered promiscuous mode
[12227.019765] virbr0: port 2(vnet5) entered blocking state
[12227.019769] virbr0: port 2(vnet5) entered listening state
[12227.179234] audit: type=1400 audit(1654891381.082:487): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-16b54d8a-be5c-4530-a8d8-ebc1bd02481d" pid=317483 comm="apparmor_parser"
[12227.233741] audit: type=1400 audit(1654891381.134:488): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" profile="libvirt-16b54d8a-be5c-4530-a8d8-ebc1bd02481d" name="/home/xlf/Documents/qemu/build/qemu-system-x86_64" pid=317485 comm="rpc-libvirtd" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[12227.256173] virbr0: port 2(vnet5) entered disabled state
[12227.257559] device vnet5 left promiscuous mode
[12227.257569] virbr0: port 2(vnet5) entered disabled state
[12227.482556] audit: type=1400 audit(1654891381.386:489): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" profile="unconfined" name="libvirt-16b54d8a-be5c-4530-a8d8-ebc1bd02481d" pid=317503 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

I've already added "/home/user/Documents/qemu/build/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 PUx," to file  `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.libvirtd` and execute systemctl reload apparmor.

Are there any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: What does `qemu-kvm -vga qxl` say?

Comment: Thanks for reminding. When I use my compiled QEMU I get: "qemu-system-x86_64: QXL VGA not available", (the system QEMU supports it). Looks like it's about spice. I installed spice-vdagent, spice-client-gtk, reconfigured my QEMU and compiled it. It seems not working.

Comment: During your `./configure` step, what does the line for "spice protocol support" report? (And the checks for runtime dependencies on spice-protocol and spice-server?)

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I realized the problem is about device compatibility. This qxl error is fixed is I changed my VM to an older machine model.